# Word comment extraction: help getting numbered headings

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, header, comments

I decided to learn VBA two weeks ago, and it's gone rather smooth. Now, however, I've encountered a problem I can't seem to solve on my own. 
 I've set up an excel document containing various modules. One of these modules extracts comments from a word document over to the excel sheet - which works as intended.

The problem is, I haven't been able to extract the first numbered header above each comment, which I'd very much like. Currently I have to do this manually after extracting the comments. As an example, I would like to also extract the first header and number above each comment, such as '2.1.1 Title'. If the comment is highlighting the header itself, it should be that header which is extracted as well.

I've tried a variety of things based on what I could find online, but every time I'm met with a variety of bugs I can't seem to fix. I've yet to find something that even sorta works. I did try one method which apparently should work in Word VBA, but I couldn't get it working within Excel.

Does anyone know how I would go about extracting the numbered headers? Any hints or tips will be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I have for the module:

```
Sub ImportCommentsDOCX()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
        "Browse for file to be imported")
    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
    '1: if no comments'
    With wdDoc
        If wdDoc.Comments.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("No comments")
        End If
        '2; Set excel headers'
        Range("B" & 1).Value = "Number"
        Range("B" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("C" & 1).Value = "Comment"
        Range("C" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("D" & 1).Value = "Highlighted text"
        Range("D" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("E" & 1).Value = "Initials"
        Range("B" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("F" & 1).Value = "Date (*Imprecise)"
        Range("F" & 1).Font.Bold = True

        '3: Extract comments and meta data'
        For i = 1 To wdDoc.Comments.Count
            Range("B" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Index
            Range("C" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Range
            Range("D" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Scope.FormattedText
            Range("E" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Initial
            Range("F" & 1 + i).Value = Format(wdDoc.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") 'Unreliable: Sometimes gives wrong date'
            'Range("G" & 3 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Range.ListFormat.ListString 'Returns empty'
        Next i
    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    MsgBox ("Extraction has completed")
End Sub
```

Comment: I think in Word the comments are applicable to the Doc whereas in Excel they are applicable to the Sheet, e.g. `Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Comments.Count`. Presumably you'll be changing where you're opening a word file to using excel?

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand, but yes, the word doc that will be opened will change. Are you saying that, I should debug to avoid the errors I've met previously in using word VBA in excel VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with some adjustments:

```
Sub ImportCommentsDOCX()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
        "Browse for file to be imported")
    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
    Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file
    '1: if no comments'
    With wdDoc
        wdDoc.Activate ' Added
        If wdDoc.Comments.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("No comments")
        End If
        '2; Set excel headers'
        Range("B" & 1).Value = "Number"
        Range("B" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("C" & 1).Value = "Comment"
        Range("C" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("D" & 1).Value = "Highlighted text"
        Range("D" & 1).Font.Bold = True
        Range("E" & 1).Value = "Initials"
        Range("E" & 1).Font.Bold = True ' Modified
        Range("F" & 1).Value = "Date (*Imprecise)"
        Range("F" & 1).Font.Bold = True

        '3: Extract comments and meta data'
        For i = 1 To wdDoc.Comments.Count
            Range("B" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Index
            Range("C" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Range
            Range("D" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Scope.FormattedText
            Range("E" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Initial
            Range("F" & 1 + i).Value = Format(wdDoc.Comments(i).Date, "dd/MM/yyyy") 'Unreliable: Sometimes gives wrong date'
            'Range("G" & 1 + i).Value = wdDoc.Comments(i).Scope.ListFormat.ListString 'Returns empty'    ' Modified ' Updated
            Dim wp As Word.Paragraph: Set wp = wdDoc.Comments(i).Scope.Paragraphs(1) ' Updated
            Do While wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString = "" ' Updated
                Set wp = wp.Previous ' Updated
            Loop ' Updated
            Range("G" & 1 + i).Value = wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString ' Updated
        Next i
    End With
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    MsgBox ("Extraction has completed")
End Sub
```

Please note my comments: Added and Modified

1. wdDoc.Activate was required at least on my computer, otherwise the
   Range property is empty.
2. After initials a wrong column was bolded
3. The original text is referred to by the Range property, not the Scope (which is the content of the comment), so its ListFormat property should be used
4. The row index was not correct (3 instead of 1)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I just ran a test on a document containing 13 comments. It appears the changes you've made extracts the header number when the comment is highlighting the header itself (This is in part what I want, so thank you for that :) ). However, nothing is returned for comments between headers. That is, it does not get the header number for comments found within a section of the document (such as a comment highlighting normal text).

Comment: I made another module which runs through all the paragraphs of a word document. I've tried using this earlier for getting the header numbers. However, I can't figure out which paragraph a certain comment is referencing.

Comment: Refer to the lines with the comment 'Updated.

Comment: Lovely. I had to add some error handling to avoid runtime error 91, but it seems to be working :) Thank you so much. I do get a strange question mark in a box for some of the comments who are made before any numbered header, but that's no biggie, just sorta odd. Once again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks working for me:

This requires Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5

```
Sub commentaires()

   Dim regexOne As Object
   Set regexOne = New RegExp

   regexOne.Pattern = "^\d+\."

   Dim s As String, s1 As String
   Dim cmt As Word.Comment
   Dim doc As Word.Document

   For Each cmt In ActiveDocument.Comments

      Dim wp As Word.Paragraph
      Set wp = cmt.Scope.Paragraphs(1) ' Updated
      Do While Not regexOne.Test(wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString)
         Set wp = wp.Previous ' Updated
      Loop ' Updated
        
      s = s & _
        wp.Range.ListFormat.ListString & ";" & _
        cmt.Reference.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & ";""" & _
        cmt.Scope & """;""" & _
        cmt.Range.Text & """ " & vbCr

    Next

    Dim f As Integer
    f = FreeFile   
    Open "c:\comments.csv" For Output As #f
    Print #f, s
    Close #f

End Sub
```